# How to fix:Not Able to create mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create mvc project but i am getting following errors:

```
  1)Severit Code Description    Project File    Line    Suppression 
     State Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Controller' could 
     not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
   reference?)  WebApplication5  
      C:\Users\shashi\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5
     \Controllers\HomeController.cs 9   Active

 2)Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression 
 State Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebApplication5  C:\Users\shashi\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Controllers\HomeController.cs12Active

3)Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression 
   State  Error CS0103 The name 'View' does not exist in the current 
   context  WebApplication5  
  C:\Users\shashi\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Controllers
  \HomeController.cs    21  Active
```

But i am already downloaded mvc package

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.7

But it is not resolving.[image]

How can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? VS 2015 and 2017 come with MVC 5 out of the box.  Assuming you're using one of these versions, just add a new ASP.NET Web Application.  On the next screen you can just select the MVC checkbox and it will all be loaded for you.